# ERROR EN EL MODAL, TAG con falla

Tags: javascript, modal, dom

Les escribo para pedirle apoyo en lo siguiente, Quisiera saber por que motivo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JQuery only -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prueba.css" />


</head>

<body>

    <br>
    <h2 class="lines-effect">La Historia de mi Vida</h2>

    <br>
    <button onclick=btnButton() class="btn btn-primary">Abrir Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-modal="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal Body Text goes here:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p>Modal Body Text goes here:</p>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-modal="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-modal="modal" aria-label="Close">Save Change</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <script>
        function btnButton() {
            alert("hola");
            document.getElementById("modal").modal("show");
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Debe ser algún llamado o disparador o el nombre del tag que pueda funcionar, no se por que el document.ElementById no funciona.

> Error :
> 6div-diagonal.html:120 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function
> at btnButton (div-diagonal.html:120)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (div-diagonal.html:82)
> btnButton @ div-diagonal.html:120
> onclick @ div-diagonal.html:82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, getElementById es una funcion que devuelve un nodo DOM y entre sus metodos no estan el metodo "modal()".

Es mejor que leas la documentacion de bootstrap sobre modales y su js.